# On mobile browsers how do I properly authorize and sign a message in a single wallet session

Tags: solana-wallet-adapter, mobile, mobile-wallet-adapter

I work on a **React (Next.js) web** project which connects to a **NestJS backend**.

The process of wallet authentication on server is the following:

1. wallet connects to our frontend app
2. frontend sends the wallet address to our backend which generates a one time password for it
3. wallet then signs a message (one time password)
4. frontend sends the encoded signature back to backend
5. backend verifies the message with wallets public key

I'm integrating my dApps with mobile libraries now and experiencing issues.

This is my `handleConnectPress` function for mobile handling of "Connect" button press:

```
    const { authorizeSession, selectedAccount } = useAuthorization();
    const [authorizationInProgress, setAuthorizationInProgress] = useState(false);
    const web3Auth = useWeb3Auth(http); // API requests for my backend service

    const handleConnectClick = useGuardedCallback(async () => {
        try {
            if (authorizationInProgress) {
                return;
            }
            setAuthorizationInProgress(true);
            await transact(async (wallet) => {
                const freshAccount = await authorizeSession(wallet);
                const account = selectedAccount ?? freshAccount;

                const oneTimePassword = await web3Auth.requestPassword(account.publicKey.toString());
                const message = new TextEncoder().encode(oneTimePassword);

                const [signedMessage] = await wallet.signMessages({
                    addresses: [account.address],
                    payloads: [message],
                });
                const signature = signedMessage.slice(-64);
                const encoding = bs58.encode(signature);
                await web3Auth.connectWallet(encoding, account.publicKey.toString()); // authenticates wallet on backend
            });
        } finally {
            setAuthorizationInProgress(false);
        }
    }, []);
```

NOTE: `useAuthorization` is reused from [example-react-native-app](https://github.com/solana-mobile/mobile-wallet-adapter/blob/main/examples/example-react-native-app/utils/useAuthorization.tsx)

Below I'm attaching what I want to achieve.
First example with the "Fake dApp" show that in a single click we can authorize the wallet, sign a message and have the connected state in the app (`useWallet.wallet` is not empty). Second example is my current implementation and it works with authorization and message signing, but **`wallet` state is empty**!

"Fake dApp" source code is located on this [repo](https://github.com/solana-mobile/mobile-wallet-adapter/tree/main/android/fakedapp) but I just fail at finding the correct code snippet from there which I could reuse...

[image]

Comment: I don't know enough about the Web3Auth SDK. Is there anything about that call to `web3Auth.connectWallet()` that would cause a _React_ rerender? If not, it's likely that you're getting connected, but nothing actually triggers React to rerender with that new fact.

Comment: That's my local hook with a bit confusing name but essentially it just calls an authenticated endpoint `https://d-reader-backend.herokuapp.com/api#/Auth/AuthController_connect` in order to obtain the access token. I don't believe it causes a rerender since it only updates the http.headers.default.authorization and stores the key in LS, but I have a feeling like I've had something else cause a rerender so it should all be there. I'll check now and update with a new comment

Comment: No, `web3Auth.connectWallet` indeed doesn't rerender any of the components whilst a regular `connect` from `useWallet` does.

I've forced a rerender on components like `FundAccountButton.tsx` but without luck. I'll troubleshoot a bit more before coming to some more meaningful conclusions

Comment: I've figured out a solution but staying offline for a few days. Until I update the question with a proper answer (and a working code example!), anyone that has this same issue please feel free to drop me a message on discord "Josip Volarević#3099" so you don't have to wait for my update

There is a somewhat complete working code here: https://github.com/open-sauce-labs/solomon/tree/master/src/components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detect if wallet adapter is a mobile one: `wallet.adapter.name === 'Mobile Wallet Adapter'` and if it is use one of the two approaches:

1. use 2 separate buttons - one for connecting the wallet (authorizing your dApp within the mobile wallet) and one for signing the message
2. have a single "authorize and sign" button with a custom `transact` implementation

Roughly something like the following:

```
await transact(async (mobileWallet) => {
  // authorizeSession prompts for authorizing your dApp within the wallet dApp
  const freshAccount = await authorizeSession(mobileWallet)
  if (typeof onAuthorize === 'function') {
    const account = selectedAccount ?? freshAccount
    // onAuthorize prompts for message signing under the hood
    await onAuthorize(mobileWallet, account)
  }
})
```